# Repeat HTTP call until the desired value is returned with RxJs

Tags: angular, typescript, http, rxjs

I need to repeat the query if the field of the returned object has the value 'INPROGRESS' with a delay so as not to clog up the server.
If another field value is returned, the loop stops and I perform some action in `subscribe()` with its response.

My attempts so far have ended up with this code, where unfortunately the queries repeat infinitely.

```
this.service
.query(id: number)
.pipe(
  repeatWhen(obs => obs.pipe(delay(1000))),
  filter((response) => response.Status === 'INPROGRESS'),
  take(1),
)
.subscribe(...)
```

Comment: have you tried with a recursive function?

Comment: @Zerotwelve No, how can i achieve that?

Comment: The functionality you are looking for can be achieved by using [skipWhile](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/skipWhile)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

rxjs has **[expand](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/expand)** operator which will allow us to make recurive api call

**Try this**

```
 this.service
      .query(id: number)
      .pipe(
        delay(1000),
        expand((response: any) => {
          if (response.Status === 'INPROGRESS') {
            return return this.service
          .query(id: number).pipe(delay(1000));
          }
          return EMPTY;
        }),
        takeLast(1)
      )
      .subscribe(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

- **RxJS 6.x**

```
this.service.query(id: number).pipe(
  repeatWhen(delay(1000)),
  skipWhile((response) => response.Status === 'INPROGRESS'),
  take(1),
).subscribe(...)
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-cc1ekf

- **RxJS 7.5.x**

```
this.service.query(id: number).pipe(
  repeat({ delay: 1000 }),
  skipWhile((response) => response.Status === 'INPROGRESS'),
  take(1),
).subscribe(...)
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-kafps9

Comment: @TalVik99, Try this
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-slvov1

Answer (score 2):

This is the straight forward way I could think of without any recursions.

1. `timer` function to emit a value at a regular interval
2. `switchMap` operator to trigger the HTTP request for each emit from `timer`
3. `filter` operator to stop triggering the `subscribe`'s `next` callback for each emit.
4. `takeWhile` operator *with* `inclusive` parameter set to `true` to close the observable based on a condition *and* emit the last value that failed the condition. This could in this case also be `take(1)` since our `filter` condition would block the other emits.

```js
const RESPONSE_IN_PROGRESS: string = 'INPROGRESS';
const POLL_INTERVAL: number = 1000;

timer(0, POLL_INTERVAL).pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.service.query(id)),              // <-- trigger the request
  filter((res: any) =>                                  // <-- stop triggering subscribe `next` callback for each emit
    res.Status !== RESPONSE_IN_PROGRESS
  ),         
  takeWhile(                                            
    (res: any) => res.Status === RESPONSE_IN_PROGRESS,  // <-- close the observable when the condition fails
    true                                                // <-- emit the last notification that failed the condition
  ) 
).subscribe({
  next: (res: any) => {
    // handle response
  },
  error: (error: any) => {
    // handle error
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

with a recursie function, something like this should do the job:

```js
private myFunc(){
    this.myRecursiveFunc(1).subscribe(response => console.log(response));
}


private myRecursiveFunc(id: number, response?:any):Observable<any>{
    if(response && response.Status !== 'INPROGRESS'){
        return of(response);
    }
    return this.service.query(id).pipe(
        delay(1000),
        concatMap(response => this.myRecursiveFunc(id, response)
    );
}
```