# RxJs retryWhen throwing exception before all retry attempt

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I'm trying to implement an api call that will be

1. retried few times if there is any errors
2. after a specific time delay
3. with some other condition check like  - if returned success response json has any field null, I'll retry the api call

I tried to implement what is mentioned here - [Rxjs Retry with Delay function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979131/rxjs-retry-with-delay-function)

Following is my code segment

Api call

```js
    delay = 5000;
    retryCount = 5;
    return this.httpClient.post(http://localhost:8080/info,JSON.stringify(data))
    .pipe(
      retryWhen(errors => 
          errors.pipe(
            delay(this.delay), 
            take(this.retryCount),
            tap(val => {
              console.log('Retrying.');
            }),
            concatMap(() => Observable.throw(new Error('Retry limit exceeded!')))
          )
        )
    );
```

Processing the response

```js
this.searchService.searchInfo(param1, param2).subscribe(data => { this.handleSuccessResponse(data) }, (error) => {
        if (error) {
          // Handle specific error here
          handleErrorResponse(error);
        }
});


handleSuccessResponse(data){
  // handle success response here
}

handleErrorResponse(error){
  // Handle generic error here
}
```

The issue I am getting, before retrying for 5 times as I mentioned in the code, the exception in the concatMap is getting throwed. What I am missing here?

I'm using RxJS 6.4 with Angular12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through the [`learnRxjs`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/retrywhen) docs and got this generic method, which seems to satisfy your requirement!

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { _throw } from 'rxjs/observable/throw';
import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer';
import { mergeMap, finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

export const genericRetryStrategy =
  ({
    maxRetryAttempts = 3,
    scalingDuration = 1000,
    excludedStatusCodes = [],
  }: {
    maxRetryAttempts?: number;
    scalingDuration?: number;
    excludedStatusCodes?: number[];
  } = {}) =>
  (attempts: Observable<any>) => {
    return attempts.pipe(
      mergeMap((error, i) => {
        const retryAttempt = i + 1;
        // if maximum number of retries have been met
        // or response is a status code we don't wish to retry, throw error
        if (
          retryAttempt > maxRetryAttempts ||
          excludedStatusCodes.find((e) => e === error.status)
        ) {
          return _throw('Retry limit exceeded!');
        }
        console.log(
          `Attempt ${retryAttempt}: retrying in ${
            retryAttempt * scalingDuration
          }ms`
        );
        // retry after 1s, 2s, etc...
        return timer(retryAttempt * scalingDuration);
      }),
      finalize(() => console.log('We are done!'))
    );
  };
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3gdv2n)

Answer (score 2):

**Case 1**

1. If `res === null` always `repeat` (delay 500ms)

> [Repeat HTTP call until the desired value is returned with RxJs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73398696/19768317)

2. `retry` 5 times if API Error (delay 500ms)

> [Rxjs Retry with Delay function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73454335/19768317)

- **RxJS 6.3 ⬆**

```
// RxJS 6.x
api$.pipe(
    repeatWhen(delay(500)),
    skipWhile((res) => res === null),
    take(1),
    retryWhen(delayWhen((err, i) => i < 5 ? timer(500) : throwError(err)))
).subscribe(observer);
```

- **RxJS 7.x**

```
// RxJS 7.x
api$.pipe(
    repeat({ delay: 500 }),
    skipWhile((res) => res === null),
    take(1),
    retry({ count: 5, delay: 500 })
).subscribe(observer);
```

**Case 2**

1. `res === null` + **API Error** = 5 times (delay 500ms)

- **RxJS 6.3 ⬆**

```
// RxJS 6.x
api$.pipe(
    skipWhile((res) => res === null),
    throwIfEmpty(),
    retryWhen(delayWhen((err, i) => i < 5 ? timer(500) : throwError(err)))
).subscribe(observer);
```

- **RxJS 7.x**

```
// RxJS 7.x
api$.pipe(
    skipWhile((res) => res === null),
    throwIfEmpty(),
    retry({ count: 5, delay: 500 })
).subscribe(observer);
```